# adding a sort feature for a table data called from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to sort data in my table called from mysql database,i know its basic but i seen to get confuse,i trying  to put `a href tags` in the `th tags` but it seems they are not working,this is my code below

```
<?php

include'includes/connect.php';

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers")
or die(mysql_error());

echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='10'>";
echo "<tr>
<th><font color='Red'>Id</font></th>
<th><font color='Red'>First Name</font></th>
<th><font color='Red'>Last Name</font></th>
<th><font color='Red'>Address</font></th>
<th><font color='Red'>Phone Number</font></th>
</tr>";

while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $sql ))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['id'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['first_name'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['last_name'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['address'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo '<td><b><font color="#663300">' . $row['phone_number'] . '</font></b></td>';
echo "</tr>";

}

echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Sorting depends in what order you fetch the records, like `ORRDER BY column name` and not on hrefs and for your info, `font` tag is deprecated, use CSS instead

Comment: i know im not saying im sorting using hrefs tags i want to add a link in a colomn say first name column the i run a query order but first name but im not able to put href tags inside the th tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i recommended to use some jquery lite plugins to sort a table

like :

[tablesorter](http://tablesorter.com/docs/#Demo)

[table fixed header](http://www.tablefixedheader.com/demonstration/)

[stupid table](http://joequery.github.io/Stupid-Table-Plugin/)

Answer (score 0):

you need to use `ORDER BY` function

```
 mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers ORDER BY YOURFIELD ASC")
```

change `YOURFIELD` with the field you want

change `ASC` with `DESC` to change order

**Documentation** [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)

Comment: i want to add a link in a colomn say first name column the i run a query order but first name but im not able to put href tags inside the th tags

Comment: you either need a `form` with `action` on the same page so you can handle wich column you want to order or handle change with `jquery`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your header sortable than you should try this.

add this 'a href="yourPHP path&sortingHeader=id"' as href to your header for example ID

Note:-and you should also add a little bit code of javascript in your php header above the
 sql query

$sortingHeader = $_GET["sortingHeader"];

$subquery = "";

if ($sortingHeader != null && $sortingHeader  != ''){

subquery = "order by "+$sortingHeader;

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers"+$subquery );

try this.....hope it will resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to make your header sortable than you should try this.

"a href='yourPHP path&sortingHeader=id'> add this as hyperlink to your headers for ex:- Id

Note:-and you should also add a little bit code of javascript in your php header above the
 sql query

$sortingHeader = $_GET["sortingHeader"];

$subquery = "";

if ($sortingHeader != null && $sortingHeader  != ''){

subquery = "order by "+$sortingHeader;

}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM customers"+$subquery );

try this.....hope it will resolve your problem.